# React: is it true that react completes all updates within one cycle of reflow

Tags: reactjs, dom

Through all presentations I'm hearing that React may update DOM within one cycle of reflow, but I cannot understand how it may complete using DOM API. What do I mean. For example, I need to update 3 attributes for ***p*** tag. I would complete it via DOM API:

```
let element = document.getElementById('el');
element.width = '10px';
element.height = '20px';
element.style.margin = '1px';
```

This code invokes reflow 3 times. And if I understand correct, React cannot gather these updates within one reflow as well. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by reflow?

Comment: When browser starts recalculating layout. In my example, browser rebuilds layout after I change element's width. After I change height it starts new recalculating layout again.

Comment: @NinoFiliu i never hear of it ether. check this out https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: @Alireza Have a look at this article than https://www.sitepoint.com/10-ways-minimize-reflows-improve-performance/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the following code

```
let element = document.getElementById('el');
element.width = '10px';
element.height = '20px';
element.style.margin = '1px';
```

invokes only one reflow. The explanation is quite lengthy, luckily [2mn of this Jake Archibald's talk](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1199) perfectly explain this.

Basically, the four lines of code only trigger actions in memory, ie variables are changed, and it's only at the end of the task (after the fourth line) that css is actually re-calculated, and the element re-rendered, and the window re-painted. So, only one *reflow*.

React, well, does the same thing, so only one reflow as well.

Comment: Ok. Let's imagine, we should update 2 different DIVs in different places of DOM tree. Can react gather these updates in one cycle of reflow?

Comment: It's really hard to answer without looking at the code. I'd advise you to check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) my MDN about the event loop and see for yourself